# Github pages only rendering the readme file

Tags: reactjs, git, github

here is my repo:
https://github.com/kalrasarthak/ReFash

and heres the pages link:

https://kalrasarthak.github.io/ReFash/

i tried solutions from the solutions available here but those are differnt now as of that solution.

How can I resolve the issue of my website hosted on GitHub Pages only showing the README page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior, per the [GitHub Pages docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site):

> GitHub Pages will look for an index.html, index.md, or README.md file as the entry file for your site.

You need to provide an `index.html` or `index.md` file at the top level (not inside a directory!), or put your content into `README.md`.